# Generating colors HEX in Excel

Tags: excel, colors, excel-formula, hex

I have data saved in Excel as numbers with calculated cumulative result (sum of all cumulative values is 100).

```
***********************************
*Result*Cumulative*      RGB      *
* 230  *    30    * HEX (darkest) *
* 100  *    10    * HEX (lightest)*
*  ... *   ...    *      ...      *
***********************************
```

I want to write function/generate color "code" in HEX which will be result of cumulative values. The highest value should have the darkest color and the lowest value should have the lightest color.

I need to export this result in CSV to another program so it's not possible to use build in function to generate color.

Comment: Can you give some expected output? You can convert decimals to hexadecimals by using `=DEC2HEX()`

Comment: Result should be something like this (http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/color-scales.html) but instead colors I want to get color code for every cumulative value. For example, result 230 should be with HEX #ce1126 (red) in column RGB. Result 100 should have HEX #FCEE21 (yellow) in column RGB.

Comment: Could you please explain how you convert 230 -> #CE1126 and 100 -> #FCEE21?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this VBA:

```
Public Const MaxR = &HCC
Public Const MaxG = &HDD
Public Const MaxB = &HFF

Public Const MinR = &H33
Public Const MinG = &H44
Public Const MinB = &H55

Public Function GETHEXCOLOR(Value As Double) As String
    Dim R, G, B As Integer
    R = Round(Value * (MaxR - MinR) + MinR)
    G = Round(Value * (MaxG - MinG) + MinG)
    B = Round(Value * (MaxB - MinB) + MinB)
    GETHEXCOLOR = "#" _
        & Application.WorksheetFunction.Dec2Hex(R, 2) _
        & Application.WorksheetFunction.Dec2Hex(G, 2) _
        & Application.WorksheetFunction.Dec2Hex(B, 2)
End Function
```

How to use: specify consts for brightest and darkest colors (in my case - `#CCDDFF` and `#334455`). Call from the cell:

```
=GETHEXCOLOR(0.45)
```

`0.45` - is your cumulative value in percentage.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I am looking for :-) Unfortunatelly, when I try to run this script I get error message "Compilation error: Constants, fixed-length strings, arrays, user-defined types and Declared statements not allowed as Public members of object. I have Excel 2010. Is it problem with version of my Excel or somewhere in script? Thanks!

Comment: Try replacing `Public Const` with `Private Const`. What happens?

Comment: Hvau, it works! :-) I would give you as many votes as I can :-) I just replaced global constants to private ones. Public function is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the formula to generate hex values from the RAND function:

=TEXT(DEC2HEX(RAND()*255),"00")&TEXT(DEC2HEX(RAND()*255),"00")&TEXT(DEC2HEX(RAND()*255),"00")

Answer (score 0):

Whatever floats your boat. This sub gives you the greyscale string with 100 giving "#000000" i.e. black and 0 giving white.

```
Sub ert()
Dim hx As String
CummNum = Cells(1, 1).Value 'number Between 0 and 100
Lightness = Int(255 - CummNum * 2.55)
slhx = Application.WorksheetFunction.Dec2Hex(Lightness)
hx = IIf(Len(slhx) = 2, slhx, 0 & slhx)
hxc = "#" & hx & hx & hx
MsgBox hxc
End Sub
```